# tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU') crashes the kernel and jupyter notebook server

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras

I am facing a weird problem.

My tensorflow version is 1.14.0 , tensorflow-gpu version is 1.14.0
My keras version is 2.3.0.

I have 5 gpus.

[image]
Python version is 3.6

My NVCC version is 10.0

My cuDNN version is 7.6

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 1
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"
```

Problem is that

```
logical_gpus=tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
```

this cell in my jupyter notebook makes the entire jupyter server crash.

I could not come up with any solution till now.

Please help.

Comment: Having similar issue that I've not been able to solved for 2-3 days with proper research only that I'm experiencing in jupyter. If I will be able to solve it, I will let you know.

Comment: @DukeLover, Is your issue resolved? If so, can you please specify the solution here for the benefit of the Community. Thanks!